# Is there any limit of json size ajax post request?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Im postsing textarea content thourgh ajax to django.
My problem starts. When i put < 1000 lines of text area, not thing happens and it's works okay. But if it put 1000 lines or greater than 10000 lines , i'm getting errors "Bad Requests". So my question is: Is it any limit of json post ajax, or any one have soulution of this? Thanks for help

This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: '/page-tools/inboxpage/setting_send_inbox_ajax/{{page.pk}}/',
            url: "{% url 'page-tools:page-settings-send-inbox-ajax' page.pk %}",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                function getCookie(name) {
                    var cookieValue = null;
                    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return cookieValue;
                }
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                    // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error_connection) {
                    alert(response.error_connection);
                } else if (response.error_token) {
                    alert(response.error_token);
                } else {
                    send_inbox(response.settings);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                console.log('Exception: ', exception);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my view in django:

```py
def settings_send_inbox_ajax(request, pk):
    page = get_object_or_404(PageOwnerByTokenUser, pk=pk)
    tokens_page_manager = page.tokenspagemanager.all()
    data = {}
    for token_page_manager in tokens_page_manager:
        page_access_token = token_page_manager.pageaccesstoken.page_access_token
        try:
            graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
            graph.get_object('me')
        except facebook.GraphAPIError:
            token_page_manager.delete()
            data['error_token'] = 'Token Lỗi, Có Token bị die, load lại page bạn nhé!!'
            break
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            _ = requests.get(REMOTE_SERVER, timeout=TIME_OUT)
            list_conversations = request.POST.get('list_conversations_id').split("\n")
            list_conversations = list(filter(None, list_conversations))
            list_conversations = [i.strip() for i in list_conversations]
            settings = {
                'delay_time': int(request.POST.get('delaytime')),
                'day_between': int(request.POST.get('daybetween')),
                'list_conversations': list_conversations
            }
            data['settings'] = settings
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            data['error_connection'] = 'Lỗi kết nối'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: django by default has a max size of 2.5MB allows for data transfer (excluding files) https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py (To be clear, there isn't really a limit from a javascript/ajax standpoint)

Comment: there's no limit to the ajax request itself, but serializing such an amount of data takes a while and requires quite some memory; so these are points where the browser may interfere with your code. And depending on the server configuration, the backend may decline a request with that much data attached or fail when trying to deserialize the data; again, time and memory.

Comment: @JacquesジャックYeah i will try to override it. Thanks have you take any bug like this?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, i think it's too large and im trying to re config that. Have you take any issue like this?

Comment: I have found my answer that i must re config django settings DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS > 1000. Thanks